# String outputting Gibberish

Tags: c

in my C script my input is printing out gibberish and im not sure why

heres more or less what i have on it

```
int main (int arg, char argv[])
{
    printf(argv);
}
```

this prints out giberish?

Comment: `char argv[]` --> `char *argv[]`, `printf(argv);` --> `printf("%s\n", *argv);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should yield the results you are looking for

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Check if there is at least 2 arguments. First argument is the executable name.
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        // Print out a string, followed by a new-line character.
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }
    // Exit successfully
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: After looking at your code here and some of the things I recommend to change:

The signature of your main function to `int main(int argc, char **argv)`. Here `argc` is the **arg**ument **c**ount, and `argv` are the **arg**ument **v**alues. `argv` is a double-pointer. If we consider `char*` to be a string (sequence of characters in memory terminated by a null-character, or `0`), then `argv` is a pointer to `argc`-many strings.

Secondly, to check the first program argument, consider making sure that there is in-fact an argument there. `if(argc > 1)` will make sure there is at least 1 argument to the program (the 0-index argument to a program is the executable path).

When you want to actually check the value of the first argument, de-reference `argv` to get a "string" with `argv[1] //The first argument`. Then you can de-reference this string to get the first character

```
if ( *(argv[1]) == 'f' )
{
    ....
}
```

If you want to check for a full string, rather than just a single character, consider using a function such as [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) defined in `<string.h>`.

Comment: adding ** to argv gives me an error "/usr/include/stdio.h:362:12: /../ 'const char * _restrict_' but arugement is of type 'char ***' extern int printf (const char *_restrict_format, ...);" i searched up that i need to use double quotes instead of single quotes but in all my code i dont use any single quotes (https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxvhm5i9kek8wok/bestls.c?dl=0)

Comment: Did you change it to `**argv[]`? If so, it should be either `*argv[]` or `**argv`.

Comment: ok, *argv makes the error go away, however the output becomes gibberish still

Comment: Probably because neither of those two things are what I suggested. Give me a second and I will update my answer with parts of your code.